# libffi.so.5() and libgdbm.so.2() dependency errors when installing scl Python package on CentOs machine

Tags: centos, python3, scl

I am getting the errors shown below when trying to install a python package on CentOs machine using software collection. I am wondering if it is related to the version of CentOs used and the version of the python package is being installed?

```
Package: rh-python36-python-libs-3.6.3-1.el6.x86_6 (/rh-python36-python-libs-3.6.3-1.el6.x86_64)  Requires: libffi.so.5()(64bit)
Package: rh-python36-python-libs-3.6.3-1.el6.x86_64 (/rh-python36-python-libs-3.6.3-1.el6.x86_64) Requires: libgdbm.so.2()(64bit)
```

I would like to know the reason behind these errors

Comment: I do not see that `rh-python36` is officially provided for CentOS 6, where did these packages come from?  CentOS 6 looks to provide `python33` and `sclo-python35` in the Software Collections.  If you are rebuilding packages from a different version, did you make sure the dependencies of those packages were available in CentOS 6?  Is your CentOS 6 system 64bit?

Answer (score 0):

Don't use CentOs 6 packages on CentOs 7 systems.

You can check the part between brackets below to verify if it is Centos 6 or 7

```
rh-python36-python-libs-3.6.3-1.{{el6}}.x86_6
```

In this case, it is of version 6 and I was using CentOs 7.